# Move along x axis between min and max

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a plane that moves between a min and max value, it bounces between the 2 points, but I don't want that affect, I want the plane to go to a point, and then start again on the begin point. How can I do something like that?

At the moment I tried this:

```
public class pingPongPlane : MonoBehaviour {

    public float MinX = -10.2f; // y position of start point
    public float MaxX = 55f; // y position of end point
    public float PingPongTime = 1f; // how much time to wait before reverse
    public Rigidbody rb; // reference to the rigidbody

    void Update()
    {


        //get a value between 0 and 1
        float normalizedTime = Mathf.PingPong(Time.time, PingPongTime) / PingPongTime;
        //then multiply it by the delta between start and end point, and add start point to the result
        float xPosition = normalizedTime * (MaxX - MinX) + MinX;
        //finally update position using rigidbody 
        if (transform.position.x <= 8f)
            rb.MovePosition(new Vector3(MaxX, rb.position.y, rb.position.z));
        else
            rb.MovePosition(new Vector3(xPosition, rb.position.y, rb.position.z));
    }
}
```

Comment: where did `8f` came from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Mathf.Repeat](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Repeat.html) instead of PingPong